# Does caret train function for glmnet cross-validate for both alpha and lambda?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, caret, glmnet

Does the R `caret` package cross-validate over both `alpha` and `lambda` for the `glmnet` model? 
Running this code,

```
eGrid <- expand.grid(.alpha = (1:10) * 0.1, 
                     .lambda = (1:10) * 0.1)

Control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",repeats = 3,verboseIter =TRUE)

netFit <- train(x =train_features, y = y_train,
          method = "glmnet",
          tuneGrid = eGrid,
          trControl = Control)
```

The training log looks like this.

```
Fold10.Rep3: alpha=1.0, lambda=NA
```

What does `lambda=NA` mean?

Comment: How can I pass family="binomial" and type.measure="auc" to the glmnet model using train?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`train` does tune over both.

Basically, you only need `alpha` when training and can get predictions across different values of `lambda` using `predict.glmnet`. Maybe a value of `lambda = "all"` or something else would be more informative.

Max

Comment: How can I specify a sequence of alpha values? Without giving a lambda sequence?

Comment: Something like: alpha.seq = seq(0,1,.01)

You do not need to use the exact method above. See caret documentation

Answer (score 22):

Old question, but I recently had to deal with this problem and found this question as a reference.

Here is an alternative approach:

The glmnet vignette (https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) specifically addresses this issue, recommending to specify the cross validation folds using the foldids argument and validate $\lambda$ over a grid of $\alpha$. This uses the same cv folds to validate $\lambda$ for each $\alpha$ in your grid.

The reason this may be superior to validating $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ simultaneously is that cv.glmnet validates $\lambda$ using a 'warm start' to select $\lambda$ rather than just randomly selecting $\lambda > 0$ i.e. speeding up validation and improving likelihood of have the optimal $\lambda$ in your grid (since fine grids are more computationally expensive).

Comment: This is more recently the better answer