# Elastic net regression: Should I tune for lambda at the same time as alpha with cv.glmnet?

Tags: r, glmnet, elastic-net

I am looking for the best *$\alpha$* (=ratio between L1 and L2 penalty) and *$\lambda$* (=penalty strength) for my elastic net regression model, using the R package `glmnet`. I have found my $\alpha$ by cross-validation using `cv.glmnet` & fixed foldids, following the [Glmnet vignette](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) and [Stackexchange question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84012/choosing-optimal-alpha-in-elastic-net-logistic-regression) (see code below).

**Short version:** I don't know if I have to tune for $\lambda$ seperately using the tuned *$\alpha$* OR if I should directly extract the `lambda.min` from the same `cv.glmnet` object?

**Longer version:** After I tune for my *$\alpha$* following this code:

```
#library("glmnet")

#Tune for alpha (L1/L2):
foldid=sample(1:10,size=length(y),replace=T)
alphalist <- seq(0,1,by=0.1)
cv_alpha <- lapply(alphalist, function(a){
  cv.glmnet(x, y, foldid=foldid, alpha=a, family="gaussian")
})
for (i in 1:11) {print(min(cv_alpha[[i]]$cvm))}

#cv_alpha[[9]] results in the minimum cvm and is chosen for further analyses
```

...should I directly extract the `lambda.min` from the same `cv.glmnet` object I used for tuning for *$\alpha$* by calling it with `cv_alpha[[9]][["lambda.min"]]` when extracting the coefficients, as in the code below:

```
##first run the glmnet
set.seed(1010)
elast = glmnet(x, y, alpha=0.8, family="gaussian")
## extract coefficients at specific lambda as determined in cv_alpha
beta_elast <- coef(elast, s = elasticnet[[9]][["lambda.min"]])
```

OR is it more advisable to cross-validate for the $\lambda$ seperately with a new `cv.glmnet` at the determined *$\alpha$*?

```
lambdas <- 10^seq(2, -3, by = -.1)
cv_lambda <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0.8, lambda = lambdas)
beta_elast <- coef(elast, s = cv_lambda$lambda.min)
```

Edit: Added a short version of the question further up and edited what I mean with $\alpha$ and $\lambda$

Comment: Both hyperparameters should be optimized simultaneously. So, you'd consider pairs of values $\{(\alpha_1, \lambda_1), \dots, (\alpha_n, \lambda_n)\}$. For each pair, use cross validation to estimate the generalization performance. Then, keep the pair with best performance.

Comment: @user20160 Thank you, that is very helpful! So to consider pairs of values would it be enough if I simply adapt my code from above to`elasticnet2 <- lapply(alphalist, function(a){cv.glmnet(x, y, foldid=foldid, alpha=a, lambda=lambdas, family="gaussian")})`? i.e. give a sequence of both _lambdas_ and _alphas_ in the `cv.glmnet` command?

Comment: Can't comment on the implementation, as I'm not an R user

Comment: Alright, but thank you for your reply!